# Where to get completely custom designed checks

Tags: check

Wondering if you can get custom designed (the "look") checks from Bank of America, or if not, which Banks (a few of them) offer this feature. Maybe it's possible to design your own checks independent of the banks, that would be good to know instead too. It looks like [these places](https://www.thebalance.com/best-places-to-order-checks-4164767) offer pre-designed checks (that is, you have a selection of designs to choose from), but I am looking for a place where you can hand them a design and say "print checks in this custom design I just sent you". It looks like [Walmart](https://www.walmartchecks.com/c/personal-checks/design-your-own/121) allows you to upload a background image for your checks. But I am talking about *complete* customization, such as the layout, the positioning of the lines and address and numbers and such, the fonts, etc.. I understand the font for the checking/routing numbers needs to be a standard font, but other than that.

Comment: Did you try to google this? Businesses regularly buy custom checks or blanks and print them themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get checks from a bank.  Even when the bank accepts your check order, it's a print shop (that specializes in checks and [magnetic ink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition)) that prints and delivers them to you.  Most banks won't even handle the order, they will just direct you to a short list of vetted print shops.

As long as you have the information to appear on the check (routing and account numbers, name of bank, your name and address) you can deal directly with one of these print shops, to have the most flexibility in the design.

However, while many things can vary (font, paper size, images), there are also some legal requirements (minimum font size, minimum spacing around machine-readable information), as well as practical requirements (if you want your checks to be accepted by all banks, don't break the rules of their processing equipment).  It doesn't hurt to ask for exactly what you want, though -- as long as you make it clear you want it to be a negotiable check, a competent shop should help you come up with an acceptable design.